# How to get playing audio file data in ffmpeg stream?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

Dears experts of the wonderful ffmpeg utility! Tell me please who knows this:
I want to make a 24/7 stream on YouTube of music from looped video and audio tracks.
I do it like this:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel info -stream_loop -1 -y -re \
    -i video.mp4 \
    -f concat -safe 0 -i playlist.txt \
    -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 3000k -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 6000k \
    -framerate 25 -video_size 1280x720 -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 50 -shortest -strict experimental \
    -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 \
    -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/my-stream
```

i.e. video.mp4 is spinning in a loop and from the playlist.txt file I play mp3 in turn.
With this everything is ok, everything works. But I also want to show the title of the playing track.
As for example on some YouTube radios:
[image: ytb]
[image]

With cover is perfect!

Any ideas how this can be implemented?

I know that it is possible to display text through drawtext. You can output text from a file, which you can separately update yourself. But how to get the data of the currently playing file? ffmpeg does not give such information, only stream parameters: fps, framerate... Or is it still possible to get it?

Or are there better and easier ways?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [FFprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) to extract metadata from files.